# How do I know if my CPU is bottlenecking my GPU?

Tags: cpu, gpu

I have a FX-6120 processor, and a 750 ti graphics card. How do I tell if my CPU is bottlenecking my GPU? And more importantly, how can I know what bottlenecks what in the future when I'm shopping for something?

Comment: If depends on the software.  There is no generic answer to this question it isn't a yes or no answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is going to depend on what exactly you are doing with your computer. If you are gaming, which based on the CPU and GPU you listed your GPU is most likely the bottleneck. The goal is to pick a cpu and gpu that will go together well for your specific application. I recommend searching PC builds online and basing your choices off what other people have assembled.